# vb.net appendline substring error

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in vb:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles browsebtn.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select Log File"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim filename As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Using streamreader As New StreamReader(filename)
            While streamreader.Read
                Dim line As String = streamreader.ReadLine()
                Dim date1 As String = line.Substring(6, 6)
                Dim writer = New StreamWriter("c:\" + date1 + ".txt")
                writer = File.AppendText(line)
                writer.Close()
            End While
        End Using

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

When I run it, it gives me an error:

```
"startIndex cannot be larger than length of string."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your ReadLine() obviously found a string less than 6 characters.  Check first.

Comment: The line its reading has more than 20 characters after the 6th one..

Comment: You *think* it has all those characters, but you might have hit an empty line or something.  That's why you need to check the line that you read has the contents you expect it to have first.

Comment: But the error happens on this line `Dim date1 As String = line.Substring(6, 6)`, correct?

Comment: @Neolisk The error happens at the end of the loop. When I run a debug and add breakpoints, the date has a value of "121010" which is exactly what I'm targeting, the whole thing runs until it gets to the end of the loop.

Comment: `The error happens at the end of the loop.`  Then you aren't posting the code that is causing the error.

Comment: I'm talking about the while loop. @LarsTech

Comment: cant you just add a `If Line.Length=> 12 Then` check?  It makes sense to do that just because it is external data, no matter what else.

Comment: I've tried adding that, then I get an error saying, "cannot access file" Because it is in use.. @Plutonix

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the error happens at the end of the loop? A loop end cannot throw an error. Perhaps an exact quote of what the error message says If it points at line numbers are they definitely correct (ie no changes since the build that throws the error). If in debug mode and told to break on the exception what line does it stop on?

Answer (score 1):

Several comments make no sense like the error happening at the end of the loop or how checking a string length can result in a File Access error.  Try something this:

```
  Dim Line as String           
  Dim Date1 As String

  While streamreader.Read
     Line = streamreader.ReadLine()
     If Line.Length > 12 Then
         date1  = line.Substring(6, 6)
         Using sw As New StreamWriter("c:\" + date1 + ".txt")
             sw.Write(line)
         End Using
     End If
  End While
```